# How to use requestFileSystemSync API in angular worker?

Tags: angular, filesystems, worker

In regular JavaScript worker, I can use requestFileSystemSync filesystem API as below.

```
    self.requestFileSystemSync = self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync || self.requestFileSystemSync;
     var fs = requestFileSystemSync(PERSISTENT, 1024);
```

How to use this in angular worker(.ts) file?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: the browser will not allow access to the client's file system... this would be a major security flaw

Comment: @TheFabio You mean using Angular, browser will not allow file system? This API is to access file system in the browser's sandbox and it works fine in JavaScript.

Comment: my mistake. I  just learned this is a web workers feature, and not something that provides access to the actual file system

Comment: Are you sure you want to use this? In the [official documentation for requestFileSystemSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystemSync/requestFileSystemSync) it says this is deprecated functionality that might not work at all. Probably you should look at the newer [File and Directories api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)

Comment: yes. It works fine on chromium based on browsers.

Comment: TS is a subset of JS so it should work fine anyway. Actually Angular workers are just web workers, so their code would be the same. I think you need to clarify your question, what's not working? Are you just missing TS declarations (eg. undefined `self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync`)? Is your worker "working" other than file system API?

Comment: @DDomen Yes self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync shows as undefined and yes worker is working fine other than file system API.

Comment: @Joe can you tell me if it is a TS compiler error or a JS runtime error? In case of TS, just plug this `(self as any).requestFileSystemSync = (self as any).webkitRequestFileSystemSync || (self as any).requestFileSystemSync; var fs = (self as any).requestFileSystemSync(1, 1024);` instead of the code you posted and see if it works. If it does I will answer

Comment: @DDomen It works. Thanks for your help. You can add into Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular workers are acutally the usual (web)workers, but you need to write them in typescript. Your problem is just due to the compilation of the typescript file.

Since [`FileSystemSync` API (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystemSync/requestFileSystemSync) is ***experimental*** and ***deprecated*** it leak of typings declarations. This means that the TS compiler does not know that they are present in your environment (chrome/chromium/webkit browser) and also does not know how it works.

For this you need to instruct the compiler and [`declare`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) what you have already in your browser:

```ts
// constant declarations
declare const TEMPORARY: 0;
declare const PERSISTENT: 1;

// this is the object returned by requestFileSystemSync
interface FileSystemSync {
  readonly name: string,
  readonly root: FileSystemDirectoryEntry
}

// we tell to the compiler to add these two
// properties to the type definition
// of the global window object
//
// NOTE: self is a variable of type (Window & typeof globalThis)
//       and we extend the Window interface with the following
interface Window {
  requestFileSystemSync: (type: 0 | 1, size: number) => FileSystemSync;
  webkitRequestFileSystemSync?: (type: 0 | 1, size: number) => FileSystemSync;
}

// polyfill assignment
self.requestFileSystemSync = self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync ||
                             self.requestFileSystemSync;

// usage
var fs: FileSystemSync = self.requestFileSystemSync(PERSISTENT, 1024);
```

Another way to deal with undeclared variables *(that one which was stated in my comment)* is to assume that the `self` global object is of `any` type such that the compiler will not complain how we manage it. This way is usually to be avoided, because anyone can misspell or use wrongly, with the subsequently difficulty to debug runtime errors:

```ts
(self as any).requestFileSystemSync = (self as any).webkitRequestFileSystemSync ||
                                      (self as any).requestFileSystemSync;

// NOTE: PERSISTENT is not declared so use 1, the actual value
var fs = (self as any).requestFileSystemSync(1, 1024);
// OR you can access the global object again:
var fs = (self as any).requestFileSystemSync((self as any).PERSISTENT, 1024);

// Another way is to declare new constants
const TEMPORARY: 0 = 0;
const TEMPORARY: 0 = (self as any).TEMPORARY;
const PERSISTENT: 1 = 1;
const PERSISTENT: 1 = (self as any).PERSISTENT;

// Another way is to use the angle brackets:
(<any>self).requestFileSystemSync = (<any>self).webkitRequestFileSystemSync ||
                                    (<any>self).requestFileSystemSync;
var fs = (<any>self).requestFileSystemSync(PERSISTENT, 1024);
```